# bootstrap, masonry ghost margins between items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding, masonry

[image]

I tried setting padding, margin and border to zero but the margins still exist.

They are removed only when the browser is resized.

html

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href='link.html'>
  <img class='img-responsive item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2' src='some.jpg'>
</a>
```

Comment: Make sure `img` is `display:block` and `a` also should be `inline-block`

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle or codepen please.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the display property of a list of items to inline-block every element has 4px extra on the right side.

Maybe this help you.